# JS not loading anything from the API and can't get data using map because it is null

Tags: reactjs

The code recieves an ID as parameter (tested and working), but when the retrieveMovieData tries to get from the api info about one movie it will not get anything, if i try through the browser it will.
Why isn't my code loading anything from the API? The same code worked in another page.

I tried to change as much as i can to try and test to understand the problem but nothing found to fix it.

Note: IT throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null", the reason it there is nothing there because it seems to not load anything from API (tested the url and it works).

Comment: Right, so, when the render is first called, the fetch isn't done yet. This is typically where you have some kind of... loading indicator.

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: Add logic such that it will gracefully handle the null.

Comment: What changes would you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your fetch statement.

**Try this**

`fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+this.props.match.params.movie_id+'?api_key=API_KEY_HERE')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
console.log(data)})`

It will wait for the fetch API to resolve the promise first.

**UPDATE:**

try changing your retrieveMovieData

```
 async retrieveMovieData(){
       fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/429617?api_key=5eb236e843cf6bc1114a8d8add6993a1')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => { 
         console.log(data);
         this.setState({movieData: data});
         });

   }
```

So now you can see data in your console, set the state accordingly.

**UPDATE 2.0**
if you want a single movie data then your render method should be

```
renderMovieData  = ( ) =>{
return(
  <div class="one-cros-movie col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="cros-movie-wrap">
      <a href={"movie/" + this.state.movieData.id} >
        <img src={"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + this.state.poster_path} class="attachment-movie size-movie wp-post-image" alt="perfume_xlg" />
        <div class="cros-movie-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Rating {this.state.movieData.vote_average}</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> {this.state.movieData.vote_count} votes</span>
        </div>
        <h1>
              <span>{this.state.movieData.title}</span>    </h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Could you please give me that change in the code so i don't try  and fail to appy it? I really need you to give me the changed code, because i think i will mess it after many tries

Comment: I could check it actualy loads something throught the inspector in google chrome, but how can i send that into movieData in state?

Comment: You are getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null, because of data is null {movieData: data.results}, your state is not updating, Now check the updated answer and try this, If you're still getting the error please let me know.

Comment: I don't want to console.log the "data", i want to store it in movieData inside "state", how can i do that??

Comment: I have tried to set into state variable but i am not doing it right. I need help on this

Comment: umm just follow my answer, check the console if the data you're getting is correct then set the state, check the updated answer now

Comment: Yes, the data show correctly as i want in console :) i just don't know how to set the state, i have set before but it didn't work my way, and thats why i would like you to show me how to set the state with your code

Comment: with your updated code it throws: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null   -- thats what i do not understand, why when setting it in state it does stay null

Comment: This is because this is not an array of the result, It is a single movie data, What you want to accomplish here, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your logic is wrong here, if you want to loop over multiple movie_id, you have to loop in the parent component.

Comment: I want to get a single movie data from the api and store it in state on movieData. With it i want to go to renderMovieData and with it render an html layout with some of the information that is stored in movieData as the id, title, vote average, vote count and so on

Comment: I don't want to loop, i want to render only one movie data

Answer (score 0):

I would add a hasData state field, and set that to true when the function returns the data. That way you render the "Loading, please wait" paragraph until the data returns, and then you render the movie data. For example:

```
  state = {
    movieData: null,
    hasData: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.retrieveMovieData();
  }
  async retrieveMovieData() {
    const url =
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +
      this.props.match.params.movie_id +
      "?api_key=API_KEY_HERE";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ movieData: data.results, hasData: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Movie</h3>
        {this.state.hasData ? (
          this.renderMovieData()
        ) : (
          <p>Loading, please wait</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: Ahh I didn't check the fetch function. Answer by varun gulati works above :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first if array is empty then do not mount the component. In your case it would be this :

```
 render(){
     let {movieData} = this.state;
      if(!(movieData  &&  movieData.length===0)) return null; //or any loader
      return(
        <div>
        <h3>Movie</h3>
        {this.renderMovieData()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: this happens with that change TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: If i put [] instead of null it will give the same error